# How can I receive notifications for completed GUI commands?

Tags: notification

For completed terminal commands there is [undistract-me](https://github.com/jml/undistract-me). I am looking for something similar but for GUI applications.

**Example:**

I am exporting an audio project in Audacity which takes a while. I would like to receive a notification once this export job has been completed.

Is there a generic hack that works with not only Audacity but GUI apps in general?

Comment: In general, no. There is no such hack because GUI apps complete things internally. If there's a pop-up dialog for progress, you can capture PID of that pop up, and wait till it exits and send notification then.  In theory I'd be possible to monitor if a certain GUI job runs based on whether the thread that does the job is running, but in practice it is very hard to achieve, unless GUI program itself states which thread is doing what